# iterating over test case and send data to function in java

Tags: java, arraylist

want to iterate over a test cases
Input Format The first line of input consist of number of test cases, T.

The first line of each test case consist of number of villains and player, N.

The second line of each test case consist of the N space separated strengths of Villains.

The third line of each test case consist of N space separated energy of players.

```
4
6
112 243 512 343 90 478 
500 789 234 400 452 150
6
10 20 50 100 500 400 
30 20 60 70 90 490 
5
10 20 30 40 50 
40 50 60 70 80
7
10 20 50 100 500 400  58
30 20 60 70 90 49 79
```

here i want to send the players & villains in separate arrays as the parameters to the function, here is my code but i am getting index out of bound exception at inner for loop when the size of test cases is >3

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
List < Integer > values = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > temp = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > villain = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > player = new ArrayList < > ();


 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
 values.add(Integer.valueOf(scanner.next()));
 }

 scanner.close();


int q = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

 for (int counter = q + 1; counter <= ((values.get(q) * 2) + q); 
counter++) 
 {

  if(counter < values.size())    
  temp.add(values.get(counter));

  if (counter == ((values.get(q) * 2) + q)) {
  for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
  if (j < temp.size() / 2)
 villain.add(temp.get(j));
 else
   player.add(temp.get(j));
  }
 String endresult = empire(villain, player);
 System.out.println(endresult);
villain.clear();
player.clear();

}

 }
temp.clear();
 q = (2 * values.get(q)) + 1;
 }

 }
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough points to vote down this question. This is looking like a class assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the main loop body you aren't moving your *value*-positioning variable *q* correctly, it requires augmentation, not assignment:

```
q += (2 * values.get(q)) + 1;
```